# What are the option to copy an Oracle table with CLOB column from one db server to another via COPY command?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob

Limitations that I am aware of are

1. Cannot use imp/exp dmp due to privilege in PROD
2. Cannot use SQL Loader
3. Tried the COPY command but states that datatypes cannot be copied.
4. I am trying to avoid inserting the CLOB column but still the same error datatype cannot copied is coming up. Why?
   Below are the 2 scenarios
5. `copy user/pwd@prod to user/pwd@test insert test_table (x,y)using select (x,y) from prod_table;` y is the clob column and the datatype cannot be copied error occurs.
6. `copy user/pwd@prod to user/pwd@test insert test_table (x)using select (x) from prod_table;` - the datatype cannot be copied error occurs.

Comment: Are database links an option?  The copy command was deprecated a long time ago and doesn't support a lot of new types.

Comment: It would be impossible to copy tables which are having CLOB columns using `copy` command.